# How to calculate mean and standard deviation of each channel of cifar10 dataset with pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function, pytorch

I am trying to calculate mean and standard deviation of each channel of cifar10 dataset. I try this code:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])

cifar10_train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)

cifar10_test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
# creating concatenated train and test cifar10 dataset
cifar10_dataset = torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset([cifar10_train_dataset, cifar10_test_dataset])

mean = 0.
std = 0.
for images, labels in cifar10_dataset:
    for image in images:
        mean += image.mean(axis=(1, 2))
        std += image.std(axis=(1, 2))
mean /= len(cifar10_dataset) * 3
std /= len(cifar10_dataset) * 3
```

but i get this error:

```
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-2, 1], but got 2)
```

How could i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The utility that you are using to merge the two datasets:

```py
torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset()
```

Is intended to feed the result into a Dataloader, hence it does not expose the underlying data for direct manipulation.

If you have to run first order statistics, you are better of manually joining the `.data` attribute  of each dataset separately:

```py
import numpy as np

print(f"Train dataset mean: {cifar10_train_dataset.data.mean(axis=(0,1,2))}")
print(f"Test dataset mean: {cifar10_test_dataset.data.mean(axis=(0,1,2))}")
print(f"Merge dataset mean: {np.vstack((cifar10_train_dataset.data, cifar10_test_dataset.data)).mean(axis=(0,1,2))}")
```

Which gives us:

```py
Train dataset mean: [125.30691805 122.95039414 113.86538318]
Test dataset mean: [126.02464141 123.7085042  114.85431865]
Merge dataset mean: [125.42653861 123.07674582 114.03020576]
```

And is also way faster since the entire operation is vectorized by numpy.

Comment: why its still not in torch.tensor dimension (from 0 to 1)? i used transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]) here

Comment: I am sorry, could you reword your question better, I can't quite get it